# How to determine the normal vector to the plane of sight in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, vector, glulookat

I'm working on a kind of camera orbiting function for an application and I need to know the normal vector to the plane of sight. I think it might be the same as the line of sight vector, is it? I didn't know how to explain, so i did a little drawing:

[img http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/6233/explanationo.jpg](http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/6233/explanationo.jpg)

Comment: Before any transformations are applied, the normal to the image plane is the Z axis, so it really just depends on converting this to the coordinate system you want it in.

Comment: Do you have a transformation matrix for the 'camera'?

Comment: I'm using OpenGL's GL_Projection matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know vector that points **forward** (not "line of sight", just "forward")? You know, from camera position? "Normal to the plane of sight" points **backward**. And that's it.

Also, graphic editors normally has "text" tool that produces much better results than handwritten text. As a general rule - unless you have graphic tablet, your text editor has pressure sensitivity and your handwriting is perfect, you should use the text tool.